# How to order by updated date and time varchar Desc

Tags: mysql

How to order by date and time (varchar) in mysql query as given below code:
My date / time format is like this : **13:30:21 PM  /  27-6-2016**

**My query**

```
select * from post_home where status='1' ORDER BY edit_date_time DESC limit 0,5
```

Comment: "My date / time format is like this : 13:30:21 PM  /  27-6-2016" Yes. Fix that. Then get back to us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better practice to store the `edit_date_time` field as a `DATETIME` type instead of a formatted `VARCHAR`. Your `ORDER BY` clause would then work as is, you could index the column to speed up the query, and you could convert it to the format you have here for display using `DATE_FORMAT(edit_date_time, '%H:%i:%s %p / %e-%c-%Y')`.

If, for whatever reason, you **need** to store the field in the text format you've provided, you can sort by it by using `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to pull out sections of the date in order of significance. You'll need to `CAST` some of the values as `UNSIGNED INTEGER` because your month field doesn't have trailing zeros and therefore "12" will come before "2" if sorted alphabetically.

```
SELECT * FROM post_home
WHERE status='1'
ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(edit_date_time, '-', -1) DESC,
    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(edit_date_time, '-', -2) AS UNSIGNED) DESC,
    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(edit_date_time, ' ', -1) AS UNSIGNED) DESC,
    CAST(edit_date_time AS UNSIGNED) DESC,
    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(edit_date_time, ':', -2) AS UNSIGNED) DESC,
    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(edit_date_time, ':', -1) AS UNSIGNED) DESC
LIMIT 0, 5;
```

It isn't clear from your example whether your hour field is zero-padded, so I've assumed it isn't (9AM would appear as `9:00:00` or similar). If 9AM would appear as `09:00:00` you can simplify to

```
SELECT * FROM post_home
WHERE status='1'
ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(edit_date_time, '-', -1) DESC,
    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(edit_date_time, '-', -2) AS UNSIGNED) DESC,
    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(edit_date_time, ' ', -1) AS UNSIGNED) DESC,
    edit_date_time DESC
LIMIT 0, 5;
```

In your example, the AM/PM field is redundant since the time is provided in 24 hour format anyway (there isn't really a 13PM). If this is a typo and you need to sort `12:00:00 PM` < `01:00:00 PM` < `11:00:00 AM` you can use

```
SELECT * FROM post_home
WHERE status='1'
ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(edit_date_time, '-', -1) DESC,
    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(edit_date_time, '-', -2) AS UNSIGNED) DESC,
    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(edit_date_time, ' ', -1) AS UNSIGNED) DESC,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(edit_date_time, ' ', -3) DESC,
    CAST(edit_date_time AS UNSIGNED) != 12 DESC,
    CAST(edit_date_time AS UNSIGNED) DESC,
    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(edit_date_time, ':', -2) AS UNSIGNED) DESC,
    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(edit_date_time, ':', -1) AS UNSIGNED) DESC
LIMIT 0, 5;
```

All of these queries are dependent on the format of your string staying constant. If you sometimes see strings with extra spaces or missing fields, they probably won't work so well.